# Is there a way to expand the entire dom tree using any browser's developer tools?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, frontend

I'm finding with chrome that even if I select the body tag (or any tag, for that matter) and press option + right-arrow, some of the nodes are not expanding and I'm having to manually expand the remaining nodes which is quite time consuming. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Chrome devtools keyboard shortcuts page](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts#elements-panel), you can use `Ctrl + Alt + click the arrow icon` on Windows / Linux or `Opt + click on arrow icon` for Mac.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I overlooked that - I was using the option + arrow-key instead of option + clicking.